# Prove a slightly different version of Fitting's Lemma.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $F$-vector space and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. The problem asks to prove that there exist subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ such that: $V_1$ and $V_2$ are $T$-invariant spaces; $V=V_1 \oplus V_2$; $T$ acts as a nilpotent map on $V_1$; $T$ acts as an isomorphism on $V_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V_1= \{v \in V\,|\,\exists n\in\mathbb{N}\, T^{n}(v)=0\}$. Clearly $V_1$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Perhaps you can finish from here?